# Python parsing XML using ElementTree based on IF Conditions

Tags: python, xml, scripting, elementtree

Using Python, I'm trying to parse an XML file to retrieve the value of an element based on the value of the 'name' attribute AND the value of a child element based on the value of the 'name' attribute as well.

The conditions are:

If Category attribute is 3 in 'test' element, then grab the value of the 'name' attribute

AND

Grab the value of the 'color' element IF the value of the 'name' attribute is 'enable'

Example Code:

```
<test category="1">
 <test category="2">
  <test name="1" category="3">
   <color name="disable">blue</color>
   <color name="disable">yellow</color>
   <color name="enable">red</color>
   <color name="disable">orange</color>
  </test>
  <test name="2" category="3">
   <color name="disable">green</color>
   <color name="disable">purple</color>
   <color name="enable">white</color>
   <color name="disable">gray</color>
  </test>
 </test>
</test>
```

Expected Results:

1 red

2 white

My Current Code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('C:/colors.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for test in root.getiterator('test'):

if test.attrib['category']=="3":
    print test.attrib['name']
```

This gives me:

```
1
2
```

I've tried a nested FOR to get the value of the color element, but everything I tried seems to start from the beginning.

Any assistance would be appreaciated!

Thanks

Comment: Something's amiss. That xml does not parse for me using ElementTree.

Comment: It's broken according to https://www.xmlvalidation.com/ as well.

Comment: Yes sorry, I was trying to do it from memory a sample of it. I updated it and it should validate now... thx for letting me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Keep in mind your XML is malformed (attribute values should be in quotes)
- Mismatching `color` tags

Your logic uses 2 conditions which are missing from your code.

```
string = '''<test category="1">
<test category="2">
<test name="1" category="3">
<color name="disable">blue</color>
<color name="disable">yellow</color>
<color name="enable">red</color>
<color name="disable">orange</color>
</test>
<test name="2" category="3">
<color name="disable">green</color>
<color name="disable">purple</color>
<color name="enable">white</color>
<color name="disable">gray</color>
</test>
</test>
</test>'''

from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

root = ET.fromstring(string)

for test_node in root.iter('test'):
    if test_node.attrib['category'] == "3":
        for color_element in test_node.iter('color'):
            if color_element.attrib['name'] == 'enable':
                print(test_node.attrib['name'], color_element.text)

#  1 red
#  2 white
```

Comment: Ah.. perfect! Thanks